# How to create an array with all possible questionnaire paths

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to create a script to test a questionnaire. The script should create chains with all possible quiz paths. The questionnaire issues questions depending on the user's answer. How can I create such a script? My code is not working properly. Are there any other ways to make a similar script?

questions:

```js
const questions = [{
    id: "1",
    question: "q1",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "2",
    },
    answer_2: {
      text: "a2",
      next_question: "3",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    question: "q2",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1/a2",
      next_question: "",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    question: "q3",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "",
    },
    answer_2: {
      text: "a2",
      next_question: "4",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    question: "q4",
    answer_1: {
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "",
    },
  },
];

const newObj = {};

const getAllPath = (arr) => {
  const treeStructure = arr.forEach((item) => {
    newObj[item.id] = {
      ...item,
      children: [
        ...Object.keys(item)
        .filter((k) => k.includes("answer"))
        .map((k) => ({ ...item[k]
        })),
      ],
    };
  });
  const newBranches = ({
      question,
      children
    }) =>
    children.map(({
        text,
        next_question
      }) =>
      next_question.length === 0 ? {
        [question]: text
      } :
      newBranches(newObj[next_question]).map((obj) => ({
        [question]: text,
        ...obj,
      }))
    );
  return newBranches(newObj[arr[0].id]);
};

let result = {
  path: {
    list: getAllPath(questions),
  },
};
console.log(result);
```

Expected output in console:

```js
{
  paths: {
    list: [
      [{
          "q1": "a1"
        },
        {
          "q2": "a1/a2"
        }
      ],
      [{
          "q1": "a2"
        },
        {
          "q3": "a1"
        }
      ],
      [{
          "q1": "a2"
        },
        {
          "q3": "a2"
        },
        {
          "q4": "a1/a2"
        }
      ],
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I added my code, but it doesn't work as it should. Looking for other ways to do this. My code does not produce the correct structure

Comment: Desired output seems like an antipattern. An array of objects with a single variable key aren't going to be easy to use. Maybe move those keys up to the containing array and turn it into an object, or use nodes like `{question: "q1", path: "a1"}` so they're all self-similar and easy to work with. Similarly, in the input structure, `answer_1`, `answer_2`, ... should be an array, `answers: []`, access with `answers[0]` and `answers[1]` and you can easily loop over them. Overall, may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: I'm looking for other options for implementing the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @ggorlen advice and changed a little the input (it's a 1-1 change). That made it easy to use a recursion for the answer, covering all options.

When thinking about a tree data structure, recursion seems like a natural solution. The idea of the recursion `get_all_paths(id)` is to get all paths from `id` by first inspecting the immediate answers and iterating on them, getting `get_all_paths` for each of them(!) and so on. When we go "deep" we add to the current path (that's the `concat` part). When we are on same level, we add a different path to the list of possible (that's the `push` part).

```js
const questions = [{
    id: "1",
    question: "q1",
    answers: [{
        text: "a1",
        next_question: "2",
      },
      {
        text: "a2",
        next_question: "3",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    question: "q2",
    answers: [{
      text: "a1/a2",
      next_question: "",
    }],
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    question: "q3",
    answers: [{
        text: "a1",
        next_question: "",
      },
      {
        text: "a2",
        next_question: "4",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    question: "q4",
    answers: [{
      text: "a1",
      next_question: "",
    }],
  },
];


function Choice(id, answer) {
  this["q" + id] = answer
}

function get_all_paths(id) {
  id = id || 1;
  var item = questions.find(item => item.id == id)
  if (!item) {
    return null
  }
  var result = [];
  item.answers.forEach(function(answer) {
    var text = answer.text
    var next_question = answer.next_question

    if (next_question) {
      var rest = get_all_paths(next_question);
      rest.forEach(function(path) {
        var current = new Choice(id, text)
        result.push([current].concat(path))
      })

    } else {
      var current = new Choice(id, text)
      result.push([current])

    }

  })

  return result
}

console.log(get_all_paths());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give some explanation if it's not difficult?